# How to show an AlertDialog from broadcast receiver?

Tags: android

I am working in scenario in which I need to receive data from service class and pass it to Broadcast receiver. I am able to get data in broadcast receiver but I am unable to show an AlertDialog. How can i show alert dialog from broadcast receiver.

Logcat

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Error receiving broadcast Intent { act=com.demo.cisive.cisivedemo.A_CUSTOM_INTENT flg=0x10 launchParam=MultiScreenLaunchParams { mDisplayId=0 mBaseDisplayId=0 mFlags=0 } bqHint=1 (has extras) } in com.carco.cisive.Utils.BroadcastTokenCheck@f8d9855
                                                                     at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:1195)
                                                                     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6823)
                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1557)
                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1445)
                                                                  Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
                                                                     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.createSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:354)
                                                                     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.ensureSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:323)
                                                                     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:284)
                                                                     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDialog.setContentView(AppCompatDialog.java:83)
                                                                     at android.support.v7.app.AlertController.installContent(AlertController.java:231)
                                                                     at android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog.onCreate(AlertDialog.java:278)
                                                                     at android.app.Dialog.dispatchOnCreate(Dialog.java:478)
                                                                     at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:336)
                                                                     at com.carco.cisive.Utils.BroadcastTokenCheck.showDialog(BroadcastTokenCheck.java:54)
                                                                     at com.carco.cisive.Utils.BroadcastTokenCheck.onReceive(BroadcastTokenCheck.java:33)
                                                                     at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:1185)
                                                                     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751) 
                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6823) 
                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1557) 
                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1445)
```

BroadcastTokenCheck.java

```
public class BroadcastTokenCheck extends BroadcastReceiver {

      @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        String value=intent.getStringExtra("VALUE");
        boolean isBackground = intent.getBooleanExtra("isBackground",false);

       // if(!isBackground){
        if(value.equals("Completing")){
            Toast.makeText(context, value, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            showDialog(context,"Warning","Session is going to expire");
        }
       // }
    }



    public void showDialog(final Context cnt,String Title,String message){
        final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(cnt);
        // Set the Alert Dialog Message
        builder.setTitle(Title);
        builder.setMessage(message)
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton("OK",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                                int id) {
                                dialog.dismiss();
                            }
                        })
        .create()
        .show();
    }


}
```

Comment: The issue is caused by `You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.`. Just google this error for a fix.

Comment: Can you show your manifest file please?

Answer (score 0):

Start activity with a dialog theme from BroadCastReceiver

```
startActivity(new Intent(this, MsgDialogActivity.class));
```

with below theme in manifest:

```
<activity android:name=".MsgDialogActivity"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are trying to show an `AlertDialog` from a `BroadcastReceiver`, which isn't allowed. You can't show an `AlertDialog` from a `BroadcastReceiver`. Only activities can display dialogs.

You should do something else, have the `BroadcastReceiver` start on boot as you do and start an activity to show the dialog.

You should do something like this.

```
public class NotifySMSReceived extends Activity 
{
    private static final String LOG_TAG = "SMSReceiver";
    public static final int NOTIFICATION_ID_RECEIVED = 0x1221;
    static final String ACTION = "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(ACTION);
        this.registerReceiver(mReceivedSMSReceiver, filter);
    }

    private void displayAlert()
    {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setMessage("Are you sure you want to exit?").setCancelable(
            false).setPositiveButton("Yes",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            }).setNegativeButton("No",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });
        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();
    }

    private final BroadcastReceiver mReceivedSMSReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction();

            if (ACTION.equals(action)) 
            {
                //your SMS processing code
                displayAlert();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This was just an example because you don't tell hpow you want to use the broadcast receiver but this is a possible work around.